# Importing CSV Data into HTML

Tags: iphone, html, css, csv, html-lists

So I have some html code and it's basically a page with students basic info. Would someone help me or show me how to insert CSV data into the html, so that I don't have to do it manually.. Thanks. Here is a sample code. So, "Student1" , "li.picture1", student1.png, "Student 1" and most importantly the " X sample1" "X sample2" and "Y sample1" "Y Sample2" would be autofilled with csv data..

```
<div id="Student1">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>[title]</h1>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a> </div>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            window.onload = function() {
              setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0, 1);}, 100);
            }
        </script>
        <!-- for profile image -->
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            li.picture1 { background: #fff url(images/student1.png) no-repeat !important; }
        </style>
        <!-- end line customization -->
        </head>
        <ul class="profile">
            <li class="picture1"></li>
            <li class="clearfix"><h2>Student 1</h2></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="field">
            <li class="sep" align="center">Day 1</li>
                <li><h3>X Sample1</h3> <p>Y Sample1</a></li>
                <li class="sep" align="center">Day 2</li>
                <li><h3>X Sample2</h3> <p>Y Sample2</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: You need a templating language. See http://haml.info/ http://liquidmarkup.org/ and http://mustache.github.com/. There are hudreds of others.

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid you will most likely have to do that manually unless you copy it all into excel and delete everything but the key data fields

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this. One is to write a program in your favourite programming language which reads the CSV file and combines it with the HTML. Like this: (not real code)

```
read CSV into $student,$picture...

output to file '<div id="' . $student . '"><div class="toolbar">' etc.
```

Or open the CSV in excel and put a formula at the end of the line like this

```
="<div id=""" & a1 & "><div class=""toolbar""> etc.".... & b1 & ....
```

Note the doubled up quotes inside the strings.